# iOS : Contact searching in different thread

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have iOS contacts in an array. I need to perform a search on this array when the user changes the text with the keyboard, but if the contact is more then 500, then the keyboard dismisses.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        [self doPerformSearchingInContacts:substring];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [self displaySearchedFriendResult];  


        });
    });


// Function for searching
-(void) doPerformSearchingInContacts:(NSString*) serachStr {

    self.filterDeviceContact = nil;

    NSMutableArray *people = [NSMutableArray array];

    [people addObjectsFromArray:self.deviceContact];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@",serachStr];

    self.filterDeviceContact  = [people filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    NSLog(@"self.filter %@ ",self.filterDeviceContact);

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to be using `dispatch_async` to add to the main thread, otherwise it's going to become blocked.

```
[self doPerformSearchingInContacts:substring];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self displaySearchedFriendResult];  
});
```